# How to determine if a number inside a square root is positive or negative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Suppose $\overline x=(x^*,y^*) = \left(\frac{(ck_2-a)bk_1}{dck_1k_2-ab}, \frac{ak_2(dk_1-b)}{dck_1k_2-ab}\right)$ is an equilibrium point of some DE system and  $(dck_1k_2-ab)<0.$

Now, I'd like to know of what type  $\overline x$ is. I computed the eigenvalue:

$$\lambda=\frac{-\left(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2}\right) \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{ax^*}{k_1} + \frac{by^*}{k_2}\right)^2+4\frac{(dck_1k_2-ab)x^*y^*}{k_1k_2}}}{2}$$

But I don't know how to determine the sign inside the square root, Is it  positive or negative?

If I know that, then I will now if $\overline x$ it's a saddle or something else.

Comment: Note: $x^*>0$ and $y^*>0$

Comment: An alternative way is to use the Hurwitz criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\,c \cdot d \cdot x^* \cdot y^* \,\ge\, 0\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2}\right)^2+4\,\frac{(dck_1k_2-ab)x^*y^*}{k_1k_2} &\ge \left(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2}\right)^2 - 4\,\frac{abx^*y^*}{k_1k_2} \\
 &= \left(\frac{ax^*}{k_1} - \frac{by^*}{k_2}\right)^2 \;\;\ge\;\;0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Is this $\sqrt{((\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2})^2+4\frac{(dck_1k_2-ab)x^*y^*}{k_1k_2})}$ > $(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2})$ ?

Comment: @Anneliset. No, that would be $\;\ge \left| \frac{ax^*}{k_1}-\frac{by^*}{k_2}\right|\,$.

Comment: why $-$ and why the absolute value?. I'm trying to see the sign of $\lambda$

Comment: The questioned you posted asks about `the sign inside the square root`, now you say `the sign of λ`. Which one is it? Note that you can't even speak of the `sign` of $\lambda$ if it's not a real number i.e. if the expression under the square root is negative. `why the absolute value` Because $\sqrt{u^2} = |u|$ so $\sqrt{\left(\frac{ax^*}{k_1} - \frac{by^*}{k_2}\right)^2}=\left|\frac{ax^*}{k_1} - \frac{by^*}{k_2}\right|\,$.

Comment:  You already proved that what is inside the square root is positive

Comment: and now I am trying to find the sign of $\lambda$

Comment: @Anneliset. `now I am trying to find the sign of λ` That's a different question, and you should edit that into the main post, rather than late comments. For a hint, use that $|u-v| \le |u+v|$ for $u, v \ge 0\,$.

Comment: is that really hard to say yes or no, now I'll have to post a new question.