# How to know the relation between 2 unknown numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is $\sqrt{((\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2})^2+4\frac{(dck_1k_2-ab)x^*y^*}{k_1k_2})}>(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2})$?

Knowing that what is inside the square root is positive, $(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2})>0,x^*>0, y^*>0,dck_1k_2 - ab \lt 0$

Apparently it is, $\sqrt{((\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2})^2+4\frac{(dck_1k_2-ab)x^*y^*}{k_1k_2})}>(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2})$ because this $(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2})$number appears also inside the square root and also something is added to $(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2}).$

Comment: Please edit the question to include all the relevant details. Since it is clearly related to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571229/how-to-determine-if-a-number-inside-a-square-root-is-positive-or-negative/2571245?noredirect=1#comment5306743_2571245), you wrote there that $dck_1k_2-ab \lt 0\,$. If that's the case, and if additionally $k_1, k_2 \gt 0$ then the inequality here does not hold since the 2nd term under the radical is negative. However, as shown under the other question, it is true that the LHS is $\ge|ax^*/k_1-by^*/k_2|$.

Comment: @dxiv so it does not holds.

Comment: It does not *always* hold, necessarily. It *may* hold for *some* values of $\,a,b,c,d,k_1,k_2,x^*,y^*\,$, but it does not hold for *all* such values (unless there are additional restrictions or relations not covered in the post). And if you add the $dck_1k_2 - ab \lt 0$ condition, then the *reverse* inequality always holds.

Comment: @dxiv :) So this happen $\sqrt{((\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2})^2+4\frac{(dck_1k_2-ab)x^*y^*}{k_1k_2})}\le(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2})$? with the condition $dck_1k_2 - ab \lt 0$

Comment: If additionally $\,k_1 \cdot k_2 \gt 0\,$ then the term is negative$\,\displaystyle\frac{(dck_1k_2-ab)x^*y^*}{k_1k_2} \lt 0\,$, so:

$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2}\right)^2+4\frac{(dck_1k_2-ab)x^*y^*}{k_1k_2}} \lt \sqrt{\left(\frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2}\right)^2} = \frac{ax^*}{k_1}+\frac{by^*}{k_2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $x^* = y^* = k_1 = k_2 = a=b=1, c = d = 0$.  But $0 \not \gt 2$.

Just because "something is added" does not mean that "something" is positive...

---

With the added constraints, $c>0, d>0$: 
$a = b =k_1 = k_2 = -1, d = y^* = 1/2, c = x^* = 1$.  But $\sqrt{5}/2 \not \gt 3/2$.

Predicting where you are going, also throwing in $a>0, b>0$:
$a = b = c = k_1 = k_2 = x^* = 1, d = y^* = 1/2$.  But again $\sqrt{5}/2 \not \gt 3/2$.

Comment: And if c,d were positive, i.e. c>0 and d>0

Comment: @Anneliset. : The two new constraints are inadequate to ensure your inequality.  In fact, $a,b,c,d > 0$ is inadequate.  See edit.